# dynamicly build <div> with razor vb.net

Tags: vb.net, razor

Hi i want to dynamicly build a div layout depending on the data i send to view, i want make 2 rows of divs and when there is odd number of models sent to view i want the layout to close as you can see in the code every 2nd model or on last model and start div every odd model .... but when i uncomment the commented code there are errors ....
(if i am not mistaken something similar worked in with C# so i hope it's only synax error)

```
@For Each procesData In Model

        curElement = curElement + 1
        elemNumb = elemNumb + 1

        If (curElement = 1) Then
            '@<div id="row">    !Comented
        End If

        @<h3>Element number @elemNumb</h3>
        @<h3>@procesData.Name</h3>
        @<h3>@procesData.Status.ToString</h3>
        @<br />

        If (curElement = Model.Count) Then
            If (elemNumb = 1) Then
                '@</div>    !comented
            End If
        End If

        If (curElement = 2) Then
            '@</div>  !comented
            elemNumb = 0
        End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked .css file and i managed to 'avoid' my problem but if anyone knows how to solve this without bypassing the original problem i would be greatfull for answer :)

```
<div id="toggle">

@For Each procesData In Model

    curElement = curElement + 1
    elemNumb = elemNumb + 1

    Dim idName As String = "element" + elemNumb.ToString
    @<div id=@idName>

        <div class="heading">
            @procesData.Name ::::::: Status <img class="statusIMG" id=@procesData.Status.ToString align="right" src="/" />
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Dokladniejsze informacje o wskazniku (potrzebne bedzie id zeby wygenerowac partial view! zapamietac)
                <br />
                np.Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit", new { id=item.ID })
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    If (curElement = 2) Then
        elemNumb = 0
    End If

Next

</div>
```